# How to remove an object by its index position from an array stored in the localstorage

Tags: javascript, arrays, function, object, local-storage

Please see the function below, it works if I'm deleting the first object in the array, visually the item is deleted and the local storage is updated, however if I delete the second or another item it doesn't work, the function keeps the first item anyways and delete all the rest. Please let me know what I'm doing wrong.

```
const deleteNote = (event) => {
  let data = Array.from(JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("notes")));
  data.forEach((note) => {
    if (note.note === event.value) {
      data.splice(data.indexOf(note), 1);
    }
  });
  localStorage.setItem("notes", JSON.stringify(data));
  event.parentElement.remove();
};
```

Comment: Never alter a collection while iterating over it.

Answer (score 0):

You could remove the elements using the [array `filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) method.

```js
const deleteNote = (event) => {
  let data = Array.from(JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("notes")));
  data = data.filter((note) => note.note !== event.value);
  localStorage.setItem("notes", JSON.stringify(data));
  event.parentElement.remove();
};
```

Comment: It doesn't work, it is deleting all objects

Answer (score 0):

You can use a filter method like the below code.

```
const deleteNote = (event) => {
let data = Array.from(JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("notes")));
data = data.filter(nodte => note.note !== event.value);
localStorage.setItem("notes", JSON.stringify(data));
event.parentElement.remove();
};
```

Comment: It doesn't work

Answer (score 0):

if event is an Event Object, you needs get the node element from `event.target`

```
const deleteNote = (event) => {
  let data = Array.from(JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("notes")));
  data.forEach((note, i) => {
    if (note.note === event.target.value) {
      data.splice(i, 1);
    }
  });
  localStorage.setItem("notes", JSON.stringify(data));
  event.target.parentElement.remove(event.target);
};
```

Comment: It only work for the first object, if I delete the OBJ in  second or third position it saves the first OBJ in the local storage